# Was Tiffany actually psychotic or was she just acting?

Tags: silver-linings-playbook

In the movie **Silver Linings Playbook**, in a scene at the end where *Pat* confesses his love to *Tiffany* through a letter. I can't recollect the exact words but he says something like

> The only way you can beat my crazy was by doing something crazy yourself.

My question is was *Tiffany* just acting crazy to get close to *Pat* and ease out his suffering **OR** was she actually, for lack of a better term, **psychotic**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me there's a lot more evidence suggesting that she's mentally unwell than the fact she's faking.

- *She tells the story of how her husband was killed buying her lingerie because her sex drive had been low.  As a result she goes into overdrive and sleeps with everyone in the office.  These are not "normal" things to do.  What's more **she's unashamed of it**.*
- ***She compares drugs she'd been with Pat**.  I'm no expert on these drugs but unless someone had been researching for some time it would be very difficult for a non-medial professional to list them as efficiently.*
- *Her speech about Pat's time dancing with her during the Eagle's games.  For someone who loathes football **she's very familiar with statistics and patterns of their games***!

I don't recall Tiffany's condition actually being named.  Pat has bipolar disorder, his mood swings from ecstatic and high as a kite to deeply depressed and lethargic.  He's also in denial about his condition and reluctantly and erratically takes his medication - these are all classic symptoms.  In his case they were only diagnosed after the confrontation with his wife.

The deception at the end had a lot more to do with Pat's mother than Tiffany.  She'd wanted him to move past his wife (who she didn't believe ever really loved him), so much so she'd tell Tiffany when he was running so she could "ambush" him (perhaps she'd even supplied the Eagle information?).

For me someone faking a mental illness would be very difficult, I believe the film makers have given more clues about her honesty than any deceit.  What's more I don't believe it holds true to the moral of the film - two imperfect people coming together and being happier for it.

Comment: I'm no expert, but given that her major problems began after her husband was killed, I got the impression she was suffering from post-traumatic stress disorder.

Comment: @ShaneFinneran as it was never mentioned in the film (that I noticed) I didn't want to make the assumption.  I think it's quite likely you're right - however many other illnesses can be brought on or amplified by stresses.  Either way a good suggestion.